# Need suggestions on control system engineering

Tags: control, control-system, books

I am sophomore studying control systems and the problems given in the books( like Norman Nise ) look too easy. Please suggest some good book with really good problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest Multivariable Feedback Control, by S. Skogestad and I. Postlethwaite.

It's a very good textbook spanning most relevant control theory and providing quite challenging exercises for every topic. They also provide the answers to several of them in their book in the book's [website](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/skoge/book/).